# iPhone: How do you control UITextView's link color when phone number/email is recognised?

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, uitextview

I have a UITextview that has a phone number in it. I see when it detects it it turns it the standard link blue and underlines it. I just want to know how I can control that link state programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep the UITextView from converting the phone numbers to links, you can do this:

```
[textView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeNone];
```

Comment: The question is about how to control color of the emails/phone number.